# In swi-prolog, how to pretty print the Term gotten from load_xml_file('file.xml', Term)?

Tags: xml, list, prolog, swi-prolog, pretty-print

swi-prolog uses list of list of list of ... to represent XML tree. 
I tried

```
write(Term)
```

it doesn't indent good, and

```
format(Term)
```

it doesn't support list, and

```
pretty_print
```

it seems it is not for list,and it is defined in rb tree library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xml_write(+Stream, +Term, +Options)
```

Usage example:

```
?- load_xml_file('example.xml', Term), xml_write(user, Term, []).
```